# How to fit image sizes correctly using Magick.NET?

Tags: c#, magick.net, imagemagick.net

I'm using Magick.NET to generate some images for a splash screen for Android and iOS.

But I'm having some issues with the resize.

We can have a square or rectangle image and portrait or landscape but when I convert it stretches.

```cs
using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(ssimageBinary))
{
    image.Density = new Density(sstargetDensity);
    MagickGeometry size = new MagickGeometry(sstargetWidth, sstargetHeight);

    // This will resize the image to a fixed size without maintaining the aspect ratio.
    // Normally an image will be resized to fit inside the specified size.
    size.IgnoreAspectRatio = ssKeepAspectRatio;

    image.Resize(size);

    MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();

    // Save the result
    image.Write(mStream, MagickFormat.Png);

    ssnewImage = mStream.ToArray();
}
```

Can anyone help me with this? This picture shows what I get, and what I want.

[image]

Comment: Well, if you are setting `size.IgnoreAspectRatio` to `true`, then obviously the aspect ratio of the source image is being ignored. Why would you expect a different result under these circumstances?

Comment: By the way, you might want to look at the name of the field `size.IgnoreAspectRatio` and the name of the variable `ssKeepAspectRatio` whose value you assign to `IgnoreAspectRatio`. Do you notice something when looking at both names? I guess it was just a brain fart -- happens to all of us -- but it would explain a possible root cause for your problem...

Comment: I know exactly what that means and the name is just an outdated one while in tests. However, that is not the source since in my case size.IgnoreAspectRatio = true.
So if you have a constructive solution for this I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: "_hat is not the source since in my case size.IgnoreAspectRatio = true_" Well, it is as i already suspected in my first comment. "_So if you have a constructive solution for this I would really appreciate the help._" Maybe you want to revisit my first comment ;-)

Comment: Beside that property that is not the problem since I tried both with size.IgnoreAspectRatio = true and  size.IgnoreAspectRatio = false do you have any code snippet with this problem solved. One important note is that if size.IgnoreAspectRatio = false it's ignoring the size I'm passing as input and keep it as a square. I just don't know the sequence of operations needed to make the image fit the size of the rectangle without being stretched. What is the usual case for this?

Comment: Seems we were talking past each other in our previous comments. Sorry about that. Unfortunately i don't really have a solution as my last experience with ImageMagick is several years ago. But i think the right approach should be to resize the image while preserving the aspect ratio, followed by a crop operation to trim the image to the desired dimension (if you want to add a larger black "border" after resizing, there should be an operation to add a border to an image. If there is no such operation, try composing the scaled image into the center of a larger black image, i guess)

Comment: Yes..Peace :) That's a good idea and I'll try it.
Do you know if Magick.NET has a way to get the most predominant colour on an image? Just to be able to set the background colour if it  is not black?

Comment: It is possible in ImageMagick to get color histogram info (http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#histogram). However, how to achieve the same thing in ImageMagick.NET, i don't know. A quick'n'dirty google search revealed an issue report (https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/issues/193), mentioning that the MagickImage class should have _Histogram_ and/or _UniqueColors_ methods that might perhaps be useful to you...

Comment: Does anyone know what's the equivalent in Magick .NET for the following command?
 
convert YourFather.jpg -resize 240x360^ -gravity center -crop 240x360+0+0 +repage YourFather2.jpg

Comment: Answer in this post https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=36088